# Get the uid of current user in firebase firestore cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to get the uid of current user in firebase firestore cloud functions.I have tried with a sample code,But it always throws an error;is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Here is my code:

```
  exports.test = functions.firestore.document('test/{doc}')
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const db = admin.auth();
    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    console.log(context.auth.uid, 'is the uid of cuurent user');
    console.log(db.getUser(uid), 'is the current user');
    return;
});
```

this code always throws an error;i don't know why?

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/lib/index.js:291:29)
at next (native)
at /user_code/lib/index.js:7:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/lib/index.js:3:12)
at exports.test.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/user_code/lib/index.js:289:34)
at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:769:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7);
```

Comment: @Doug stevenson if you don't mind can you please post the link?

Comment: The link is there. All marked dups have it.

Comment: @Doug stevenson thank you